# iOS App crashed on IAP purchase initialization only in live

Tags: ios, cordova, in-app-purchase, crash-dumps

The production version of an iOS app crashes during in-app purchase initiation. It works fine with sandbox mode dev build. The app downloaded from live server (app store) does not. I'm adding the crash dump (masked app ids). Any help in analyzing the crash dump would be helpful. The product code is obtained from our server on initial launch. We use that info to load the IAP product info from app store on load. It's a phonegap app and uses [j3k0 phonegap plugin](https://github.com/j3k0/PhoneGap-InAppPurchase-iOS).

```
Incident Identifier: E6C64063-B833-40FF-AB22-24C310FAC3D9
CrashReporter Key:   826cfd9d4e434d4472c6dcb2960b01cf134976e1
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:             My Example Apps [252]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/35B2EB8E-91C5-4284-AE8C-252326CC9203/My Example Apps.app/My Example Apps
Identifier:          com.example.myexampleapps
Version:             6.0 (1.4.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-04-25 15:19:18.955 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 7.1 (11D169)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2f0f6fce __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x398a3cca objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2f0f6f10 +[NSException raise:format:] + 100
3   StoreKit                        0x318a3f9e -[SKPaymentQueue addPayment:] + 598
4   My Example Apps                 0x000ff9e0 0xcb000 + 215520
5   My Example Apps                 0x000ff69e 0xcb000 + 214686
6   My Example Apps                 0x000ff3bc 0xcb000 + 213948
7   My Example Apps                 0x000ff4ac 0xcb000 + 214188
8   My Example Apps                 0x000ff420 0xcb000 + 214048
9   Foundation                      0x2fadfc6e __NSThreadPerformPerform + 382
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2f0c2256 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 10
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2f0c1726 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 202
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2f0bff1a __CFRunLoopRun + 618
13  CoreFoundation                  0x2f02af4a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
14  CoreFoundation                  0x2f02ad2e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
15  GraphicsServices                0x33f2f65e GSEventRunModal + 134
16  UIKit                           0x31976168 UIApplicationMain + 1132
17  My Example Apps                 0x000d0bb2 0xcb000 + 23474
18  My Example Apps                 0x000d0b8c 0xcb000 + 23436


Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e661f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ed0792 pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39e16fd8 abort + 72
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39145cd2 abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3915e6e0 default_terminate_handler() + 248
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x398a3f62 _objc_terminate() + 190
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3915c1c4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3915bd28 __cxa_rethrow + 96
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x398a3e12 objc_exception_rethrow + 38
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2f02afc0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 636
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2f02ad2e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
11  GraphicsServices                0x33f2f65e GSEventRunModal + 134
12  UIKit                           0x31976168 UIApplicationMain + 1132
13  My Example Apps                 0x000d0bb2 0xcb000 + 23474
14  My Example Apps                 0x000d0b8c 0xcb000 + 23436

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e53808 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x39d9fde8 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x39d8ef6e _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 34

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e53a58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e53854 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2f0c1896 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2f0bffbc __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2f02af4a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2f02ad2e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x2fa6a082 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 314
7   Foundation                      0x2fadfa5a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecf916 _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecf886 _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecdaa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e66c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecdbda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecda94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e53a58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e53854 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2f0c1896 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2f0bffbc __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2f02af4a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2f02ad2e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   WebCore                         0x372bf38e RunWebThread(void*) + 414
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecf916 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecf886 _pthread_start + 98
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecdaa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e65f2c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecef22 _pthread_cond_wait + 518
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecfd60 pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x30057ee4 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 204
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x30055538 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecf916 _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecf886 _pthread_start + 98
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecdaa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e53a58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e53854 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2f0c1896 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2f0bffbc __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2f02af4a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2f02ad2e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   WebCore                         0x37307dba WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 250
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x30055538 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecf916 _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecf886 _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecdaa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 7 name:  WebCore: LocalStorage
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e65f2c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecef22 _pthread_cond_wait + 518
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecfd60 pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x30058012 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 58
4   WebCore                         0x373f21a4 WTF::PassOwnPtr<WTF::Function<void ()> > WTF::MessageQueue<WTF::Function<void ()> >::waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeout<bool (WTF::Function<void ()>*)>(WTF::MessageQueueWaitResult&, bool (&)(WTF::Function<void ()>*), double) + 104
5   WebCore                         0x373f212a WebCore::StorageThread::threadEntryPoint() + 162
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x30055538 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecf916 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecf886 _pthread_start + 98
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecdaa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e66434 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2f0c5758 __CFSocketManager + 480
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecf916 _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecf886 _pthread_start + 98
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ecdaa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x39e09aa9
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3bbcf18c      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x27d38594
    r8: 0x184ad620    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x184ad590
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x27d38588      lr: 0x39ed0797      pc: 0x39e661f0
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
0xcb000 - 0x116fff My Example Apps armv7  <5a7198333e0d3757befb8e445708f9cc> /var/mobile/Applications/35B2EB8E-91C5-4284-AE8C-252326CC9203/My Example Apps.app/My Example Apps
0x2be1f000 - 0x2be3ffff dyld armv7  <651a31c39f71311f965f8ac44de02c88> /usr/lib/dyld
0x2ddb6000 - 0x2de9efff RawCamera armv7  <8f62f266f7d539a5a388221dfe90db50> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x2deb7000 - 0x2df84fff IMGSGX535GLDriver armv7  <425beeed20553dd5bac0e7e9e8506f1d> /System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX535GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX535GLDriver
0x2df8e000 - 0x2e090fff AVFoundation armv7  <e6f4e322434733c2a6d074bdc226b08d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x2e091000 - 0x2e0b9fff libAVFAudio.dylib armv7  <0bae9ec49a9637c696edf86d86a32db6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
0x2e0ba000 - 0x2e0bafff Accelerate armv7  <0424978b39f037a7b3bf9aad5b34a5b3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x2e0c4000 - 0x2e290fff vImage armv7  <c4834965bdc638fcb1082f53a7721f42> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x2e291000 - 0x2e36afff libBLAS.dylib armv7  <cfc693306499378c9c09851259cf3563> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x2e36b000 - 0x2e621fff libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <65970a4fea383446b0b4b87e634b8dfd> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x2e622000 - 0x2e690fff libvDSP.dylib armv7  <174c13fd605a39efbb7f1314a6d1fdbe> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x2e691000 - 0x2e6a2fff libvMisc.dylib armv7  <5a8317adbade34a9b415e44ab8c64eb6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x2e6a3000 - 0x2e6a3fff vecLib armv7  <7b2718a5a22c36e6ab943b2e4bea9123> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x2e6a4000 - 0x2e6c4fff Accounts armv7  <0b9bb1f3e9393a64b396871da25800ad> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x2e6c6000 - 0x2e72dfff AddressBook armv7  <18927033ac4834f3a482884bb5dfd0eb> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x2e72e000 - 0x2e844fff AddressBookUI armv7  <0a50c4941a29367a9ed8bb713630e79b> 
....
```

Thanks.

Comment: Any chance you forgot to submit the purchase to apple? this exception may be caused by trying to purchase a product that wasn't loaded successfully by the "load()" method.

Comment: Hi, I have "Waiting for Screenshot" status in the In-App products section. Is that the reason?

Comment: @jeko Right, missed that. Thanks. Can you add it as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is probably caused by trying to purchase a product that wasn't loaded successfully by the "load()" method.

In your case, the most probable reason is that you forgot submit the purchase to apple together with the application.